# Check if node is running in private network

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, console, rpc

Is there a command in the geth javascript console to check if node is running in private net or if it is public?

For now I always had to check it in the left hand corner in mist if it's private or public: 
[image: private network sign in the left hand corner]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,

do:

```
eth.getBlock(0)
```

If the hash is 0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3 then it is public, otherwise it is private, test net or any other net that is not Ethereum Main Net.

Though, it is not 100% certain, because you may also run a public net in isolated network, and create a chain split.

Comment: My other solution would be to compare the balance of the node with the public blockchain. If it‘s the same it is a public node else private.

Comment: Why would the hash for the public blockchain always be the same (0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3)?

Comment: its the hash of the block 0, block 1 will have another hash, but the hash of the first block (block 0) indicates what blockchain are you using